# R- How to get the date part in POSIXlt

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 1 column and in POSIXlt format "2014-11-25" "2014-06-08". How can I extract the date part of this column? The result should be 25, 08

There are functions `months`, `weekdays` but I cannot find such function for date. Really appreciate your help

Comment: You mean the day? Function `day` from `lubridate` package. Or `format(x, "%d")`. You have a lot of choice.

Comment: Hi Pascal, do you know how to get just the day and month, not the year (ex: 11/25, 06/08) in POSIXlt format?

Comment: For your future knowledge, I suggest you to read `?format` and `?strptime`.